# Tkinter error: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu"

Tags: python, tkinter

Following along with a YouTube video, however I keep getting this tkinter error and I have not the faintest clue from where it originates

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

G_FONT=("Verdana", 12)


class CapApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, controller)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=G_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CapApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree the error message is confusing. Anyway, there's a couple of errors in your code — fixed and noted in comments in the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk

G_FONT=("Verdana", 12)


class CapApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    # Fixed indentation so function is a class method.
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        # You're passing too many arguments the base class __init__()
#        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, controller)1
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=G_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CapApp()
    app.mainloop()
```